# Show first and last value in table

Tags: qliksense

I have an excel file with customer's purchasing details (sorted by date).
for example:

| customer_id | date | $_Total_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/2/23 | 5 |
| A | 1/3/23 | 20 |
| A | 1/4/23 | 10 |

i want to show in table, one row for each customer, so the final table will be:

| customer_id | date | purchase_counter | amount_of_last_purchase | amount_of_first_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/4/23 | 3 | 10 | 5 |

in my table, `customer_id` is a dimension.

for extracting the date, i use `max(date)` as measure

for `purchase_counter` i use `count(customer_id)`

for extracting `'amount_of_first_purchase'`, i use `firstSortedValue('$_Total_purchase', date)`

how can i extract `'amount_of_last_purchase'`? is there maybe an aggregation function i can use?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can use `-date` in you expression and this will return the last record:

`FirstSortedValue('$_Total_purchase', -date)`

The above will work for the provided data example. When there are more than one customer then [Aggr](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/aggr.htm) function can help:

First: `FirstSortedValue(aggr(sum($_Total_purchase), customer_id, date), date)`

Last: `FirstSortedValue(aggr(sum($_Total_purchase), customer_id, date), -date)`

---

Another approach (if applied to your case/data) is to flag the first and last records during the data load and use the flags in the measures.

An example script:

```
RawData:
Load * Inline [
customer_id,    date,   $_Total_purchase
A,  2/1/23,     5
A,  3/1/23,     20
A,  4/1/23,     10
B,  5/1/23,     35
B,  6/1/23,     40
B,  7/1/23,     50
];

Temp0:
Load 
  customer_id,
  date,
  // flag the first record 
  // if the current row is the beggining of the table then flag as isFirst = 1
  // if the customer_id for the current row is different from the previously loaded >-
  // customer_id then flag as isFirst = 1
  if(RowNo() = 1 or customer_id <> peek(customer_id), 1, null()) as isFirst,
  // getting the last is a bit more tricky
  // similar logic - if the currrent and previous customer_id are different >-
  // or it is the end of the table then get the current customer_id and date >-
  // and combine their values. Values are separeted with | ELSE write 0.
  // for example: A|4/1/23 or B|7/1/23
  if(customer_id <> peek(customer_id) and RowNo() <> 1, peek(customer_id) & '|' & peek(date), 
    if(RowNo() = NoOfRows('RawData'), customer_id & '|' & date, 0
  )) as isLastTemp
Resident
  RawData
;

// Get all the data from Temp0 for which isLastTemp is not equal to 0
// split isLastTemp by | -> fist value is customer_id and second is date
// join the result back to the otiginal table
join (RawData)
Load
  SubField(isLastTemp, '|', 1) as customer_id,
  SubField(isLastTemp, '|', 2) as date,
  1 as isLast
Resident 
  Temp0
Where
  isLastTemp <> 0
;

// join Temp0 to the original table
// but only grab the isFirst flag
join(RawData)
Load 
  customer_id,
  date,
  isFirst
Resident
  Temp0
;

// this table is no longer needed
Drop Table Temp0;
```

Once the above script is reloaded `RawData` table will have two more columns - `isFirst` and `isLast`:

[image: raw data]

Then the expressions are simpler:

First: `sum( {< isFirst = {1} >} $_Total_purchase)`

Last: `sum( {< isLast = {1} >} $_Total_purchase)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# read excel file
df = pd.read_excel('customer_purchases.xlsx')

# get first value
first_value = df.head(1)

# get last value
last_value = df.tail(1)
```

you can do with pandas also